# Is it possible to get artist information like Exoplayer, metadata?

Tags: android, metadata, audio-player, exoplayer, android-music-player

I could not find the data source extension for Exoplayer with metadata support. Could you help
i still have not found

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

        try {

            if (station.getRadiourl().endsWith(".m3u8")) {

                String url = station.getRadiourl();
                emAudioPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(url));
                emAudioPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } else {

                Uri uri;
                uri = Uri.parse(station.getRadiourl());

                Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
                String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, "ExoPlayerDemo");
                OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

                DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, null,
                        new OkHttpDataSource(okHttpClient, userAgent, null, null, CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK));

                ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(uri, dataSource, allocator,
                        BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

                MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource,
                        MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, null, true, null, null,
                        AudioCapabilities.getCapabilities(context), AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);

            }
            return true;

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But I can't find any info on how to get metadata like artist and name of current song.. Is it possible to get such info?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Artist name,current song name .... use this library :

```
implementation 'com.vodyasov:amr:0.5'
```

Example :

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("URL");
 OnNewMetadataListener ilistener = new OnNewMetadataListener() {
     @Override
     public void onNewHeaders(String stringUri, List<String> name, List<String> desc, List<String> br, List<String> genre, List<String> info) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onNewStreamTitle(String stringUri, String streamTitle) {
         Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.textanim);
         a.reset();
         songinfo.setText("Song : " + streamTitle);
     }
};
```